# QLPreviewController & Keynote

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I'm using a QLPreviewController to present a keynote presentation. The keynote file is 4.8MB and my app keeps crashing because its trying to load the whole presentation into memory at once. Am I missing something here?

Is there a way of loading each slide as a QLPreviewItem then presenting these one at a time (without expanding the .key file and pulling out each slide thumbnail one by one, which sort of defeats the object of being able to use the controller to preview iWork files).

Thanks,

Brett

Comment: I also would like to know that. I'm using DocumentInteractionController which does not crash, but I would like to offer paging. You can load PDFs page by page using Quartz but I have to preview all kinds of documents.

Answer (score 2):

1. I dont think the QLPreviewController
   load all the pages at once
2. 4.8M is a supported size , cant be the reason of crash

so, read carefully the error message, maybe another exception cause the crash